# What API will allow me to detect and end the session of someone using "mstsc /console"?

Tags: windows, administration, rdp, terminal-services, mstsc

I'm having a very difficult time listing and closing the sessions of folks using Mstsc /admin.

Does anyone know the API to use if the server is a normal server and not a terminal server per-se?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [LsaEnumerateLogonSessions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378275(v=VS.85).aspx) function to get a list of all logged in sessions, and use [LsaGetLoginSessionData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378290(v=VS.85).aspx) to determine what type of session it is.

If you're only interested in remote desktop sessions, [WTSEnumerateSessions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383833(v=VS.85).aspx) might be helpful as well. If you'd like to force a logoff, you can use [WTSLogoffSession](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383836(v=VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can start with [WTSEnumerateSessions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383833%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) or [WTSEnumerateSessionsEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee621014%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).